# Linear map on $\mathcal{l}^1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Given $$\varphi: \mathcal{l}^1 \ni \{x_n\} \rightarrow \{ \frac{1}{n} x_n \} \in \mathcal{l}^1 $$

how to determine whether  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{x_n}{n}|$ is convergent based on the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$ is convergent?

We cannot use Holder inequality here, and no counterexample comes to mind.

Comment: $0 \leq |x_n / n| \leq |x_n|$ for all positive integers $n$. So $\sum |x_n / n|$ is convergent by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Bungo: This can serve as an answer.